# Use Fubini to prove that $\int_a^{x_0}\phi'(x)\left(\int_x^{x_0}u'(t)dt\right) dx = \int_a^{x_0}u'(t)\left(\int_a^{t}\phi'(x)dx\right) dt$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, definite-integrals

Let $u \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\phi \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ with compact support contained in $[a,b]$ and let $x_0 \in [a,b]$. How can I prove that the following holds

$$\int_a^{x_0}\phi'(x)\left(\int_x^{x_0}u'(t)dt\right) dx = \int_a^{x_0}u'(t)\left(\int_a^{t}\phi'(x)dx\right) dt$$

using Fubini's theorem?

I need to use Fubini theorem. This is part of the proof of Lemma 8.2 in Brezis' functional analysis book, where this statement is used to prove that the weak derivative of $$v(x) = \int_{y_0}^x g(t)dt$$ is $g$.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, are you familiar with [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts)?

Comment: @MichaelLee I tried various tricks, including writing the integrals using the indicator function and Fubini-Tonelli theorem, but nothing helped. I know integration by parts, but I cannot see where it helps here.

Comment: Write down your attempt of Fubini-Tonelli and indicator functions. That should work.

Comment: @JoaquinSan I don't see how: I get stuck with $\chi_{[x,x_0]}$, when at some point I should arrive to $\chi_{[a,t]}$. If you have the argument in mind, could you write up an answer?

Comment: Fubini-Tonelli and indicator functions is an unnecessary amount of machinery. This is a one step problem when you apply integration by parts.

Comment: @JoaquinSan By any chance, were you able to work this out?

Comment: @Rin i agree that it is unecessary.

Comment: @JoaquinSan Unfortunately I cannot use the answer below because this is actually part of the proof of the fact that the fundamental theorem of calculus holds for functions in $W^{1,p}(I)$ and Brezis explicitly says that Fubini should be applied. But I don't know how.

Comment: The only thing you need to do is take good care of your indicator functions. Try rewriting the indicator functions. (You have a product so there are several ways to rewrite)

Comment: @JoaquinSan I don't know what you mean: I'm stuck with $\chi_{[x,x_0]}$.  If you have the argument in mind, could you please write up an answer?

Comment: Is it clear with the answer?

Answer (score 1):

The left-hand side is an integral of $u'(t)\phi'(x)$ over the region corresponding to $x\leq t\leq x_0$, $a\leq x\leq x_0$. We can rewrite these inequalities instead as $a\leq x\leq t$, $a\leq t\leq x_0$ (it should be easy to check that these are the same region). This gives us the bounds of the integral on the right-hand side.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use that $U'(s) = -u'(s)$. Indeed, this is part of the proof of this fact.

Comment: It's Lemma 8.2 in Brezis's functional analysis book. I need to use only Fubini theorem, but I don't know how.

Comment: Have you looked at how Brezis uses Fubini's theorem in the book's proof? He includes a few steps that may make it easier for you (or for anybody else who reads this question) to figure out how best to present this.

Comment: It just says "By Fubini theorem", no further details.

Comment: That's because the application of Fubini's theorem is one step. Compare the RHS of the line under the words "By Fubini's theorem" with the RHS of the line above it. Do you see how Brezis has rewritten the bounds of the region of integration?

Comment: @Rin I've edited my answer. Does this explanation make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

The point is that

$$\chi_{[x,x_0]}(t) = \chi_{[a,t]}(x), \quad a \leq x \leq t \leq x_0.$$

It might help to draw a picture of the region in the $tx$-plane. Can you see that both of these functions are identically $1$ in this region?

Answer (score 0):

So I'll do what I suggested in the comments, rewriting the indicator functions.

$$ \int_a^{x_0} \phi'(t) \left( \int_x^{x_0} u'(t) dt \right) dx = \int \int \mathbb{1}_{[a,x_0]}(x) \mathbb{1}_{[x,x_0]}(t) \phi'(x) u'(t) dt dx  $$

Analyze the product of the indicator functions:

$ \mathbb{1}_{[a,x_0]}(x) \mathbb{1}_{[x,x_0]}(t) = 1 $ if $ a \leq x \leq x_0 $ and $ x \leq t \leq x_0 $ and 0 elsewhere.

Equivalently, 
$ \mathbb{1}_{[a,x_0]}(x) \mathbb{1}_{[x,x_0]}(t) = 1 $ if $ a \leq x \leq t \leq x_0 $ and $0$ elsewhere.

Check the other product: 
$ \mathbb{1}_{[a,t]}(x) \mathbb{1}_{[a,x_0]}(t)  = 1 $ if $a \leq x \leq t \leq x_0 $ and $0$ elsewhere.

So they in fact are the same function (just a rewriting of the indicator functions, now substitute and apply Fubini:

$$ \int_a^{x_0} \phi'(t) \left( \int_x^{x_0} u'(t) dt \right) dx = \int \int \mathbb{1}_{[a,t]}(x) \mathbb{1}_{[a,x_0]}(t) \phi'(x) u'(t) dx dt = \int_a^{x_0}  u'(t) \left( \int_a^t \phi'(x) dx \right) dt   $$

Hope I didn't make dumb mistakes.